# creating an object within a class - where is that object?

Tags: python, class, jython

I am creating an object X from a method in another class C. Then I am trying to reference that object in methods of that class C by passing it as an argument, but I get the error name X not defined. Is that object created in a different namespace?
The object that gets generated from the class itself is a class defined in a java script in another Module.

Module B

```
from moduleA import *
from moduleX import *

c = classC(a, b)
X = c.createX()
c.doStuffWithX(X, v)
```

module A

```
class classC(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def createX(self):
        X = someObjectDefinedInJavaLang(self.a, self.b)
        return X #as suggested by Bruno - still getting the error

    def doStuffWithX(self, X, v):
        X.useSomeMethodDefinedinObjectX(v)
```

I hope you can follow me. Tried to make the structure clear, not sure how successful I was with that.

I also tried to see if I can directly reference the object instead of through the class properties

```
c = classC(a, b)
X = c.createX()
X.useSomeMethodDefinedinObject(v)
```

This throws the same error. I know that the object gets created "somewhere" as the code runs successfully (and to do so, he needs the object as at some point the process gets picked up by java) when I dont try to further access the objects own properties

Comment: not according to that code you aren't. Typo? y= classC(a,b)?

Comment: Your `createX` does not return the created object. So that code can't work. But as to X being not defined, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Where does `y` come from ?

Comment: sorry, no iudea why I suddenly came up with y. edited, so hopefully makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

```
def createX(self):
    X = someObjectDefinedInJavaLang(self.a, self.b)
    return X
```

Comment: please post the full error message and traceback. FWIW I just runned your code snippet (with mockups for the missing parts) and I don't get any error.